# Match assertions using If else condition on JSON response in karate DSL

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

From the below response, How can I perform Match assertions using If else condition on below JSON response ?

{
"tutionFee": 22.850000,
"schoolFee": 0.000000,
"updatedBy": "Dummy",
"updatedTime": "2024-01-26",
}

My expectation is to write as below,

if (tutionFee == 21.00)
match $.updatedBy == 'abcd'
else
match $.updatedBy == 'Dummy'
end

I have tried this but didn't worked

- if (tutionFee == 21.00) karate.match(response.updatedBy, 'abcd')